# GDAL GeoTIFF to GeoPackage overview building failed error

Tags: gdal, gdal-translate, geopackage, gdal2tiles, gdaladdo

I have multiple GeoTIFFs in UTM projection. I need to create GPKG SQLite databases. I noticed that some (Example3) conversions are failing with overview error. What is cause for the failure ? How could we overcome it?

Example1:

```
D:\Raster_Data\temp>gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:4326  Kan_UTM.tif Kan_WGS84.tif
Copying color table from Kan_UTM.tif to new file.
Creating output file that is 18361P x 10657L.
Processing Kan_UTM.tif [1/1] : 0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.

D:\Raster_Data\temp>gdal_translate -of GTiff -a_srs EPSG:4326 -expand rgba Kan_WGS84.tif Kan_WGS84_RGBA.tif
Input file size is 18361, 10657
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.

D:\Raster_Data\temp>gdal_translate -of GPKG -ot Byte -co TILING_SCHEME=GoogleMapsCompatible Kan_WGS84_RGBA.tif Kan.gpkg -a_srs EPSG:4326
Input file size is 18361, 10657
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.

D:\Raster_Data\temp>gdaladdo Kan.gpkg 2 4 8 16 32 64 128 256 512 1024 2048
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
```

Example2:

```
D:\Raster_Data\temp>
D:\Raster_Data\temp>gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:4326  Pho_UTM.tif Pho_WGS84.tif
Copying color table from Pho_UTM.tif to new file.
Creating output file that is 19376P x 11003L.
Processing Pho_UTM.tif [1/1] : 0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.

D:\Raster_Data\temp>gdal_translate -of GTiff -a_srs EPSG:4326 -expand rgba Pho_WGS84.tif Pho_WGS84_RGBA.tif
Input file size is 19376, 11003
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.

D:\Raster_Data\temp>gdal_translate -of GPKG -ot Byte -co TILING_SCHEME=GoogleMapsCompatible Pho_WGS84_RGBA.tif Pho.gpkg -a_srs EPSG:4326
Input file size is 19376, 11003
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.

D:\Raster_Data\temp>gdaladdo Pho.gpkg 2 4 8 16 32 64 128 256 512 1024 2048
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
```

Example3:

```
D:\Raster_Data\temp>gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:4326  Chic_UTM.tif Chic_WGS84.tif
Copying color table from Chic_UTM.tif to new file.
Creating output file that is 20121P x 10164L.
Processing Chic_UTM.tif [1/1] : 0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.

D:\Raster_Data\temp>gdal_translate -of GTiff -a_srs EPSG:4326 -expand rgba Chic_WGS84.tif Chic_WGS84_RGBA.tif
Input file size is 20121, 10164
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.

D:\Raster_Data\temp>gdal_translate -of GPKG -ot Byte -co TILING_SCHEME=GoogleMapsCompatible Chic_WGS84_RGBA.tif Chic.gpkg -a_srs EPSG:4326
Input file size is 20121, 10164
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.

D:\Raster_Data\temp>gdaladdo Chic.gpkg 2 4 8 16 32 64 128 256 512 1024 2048
Warning 1: Use of overview factor 512 causes gpkg_zoom_other extension to be needed
ERROR 1: Could not find dataset corresponding to ov factor 512
Overview building failed.
```

Answer (score 1):

Your gdaladdo command is using just the power of two overview levels and is thus correct by the GDAL GeoPackage raster driver documentation https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/gpkg.html.

> **Overviews**
>
> gdaladdo / BuildOverviews() can be used to compute overviews. Power-of-two overview factors (2,4,8,16,…) should be
> favored to be conformant with the baseline GeoPackage specification.
> Use of other overview factors will work with the GDAL driver, and
> cause the gpkg_zoom_other extension to be registered, but that could
> potentially cause interoperability problems with other implementations
> that do not support that extension.

It may be that there is some bug in how the sizes of the last overviews are computed. However, gdaladdo does not any more require that user inputs the overview levels https://gdal.org/programs/gdaladdo.html

> A list of integral overview levels to build. Ignored with
> -clean option. New in version 2.3: levels are no longer required to build overviews. In which case, appropriate overview power-of-two
> factors will be selected until the smallest overview is smaller than
> the value of the -minsize switch.

I could reproduce the error with a 20121, 10164 sized test image that I created. Gdaladdo was running OK with command

```
gdaladdo ovrtest.gpkg
```

Overview levels which were created are 2 4 8 16 32 64 128

```
Overviews: 10060x5082, 5030x2541, 2515x1271, 1258x635, 629x318, 314x159, 157x79
```

If you are not satisfied with letting GDAL to decide the overview levels you should write mail to gdal-dev mailing list and ask if you have found a bug. It seems that error happens with any 20121, 10164 sized GeoPackage raster with command

gdaladdo ovrtest.gpkg -minsize 40

**EDIT**

The GDAL issue was fixed 2020-08-07 by pull request https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/pull/2860.

Comment: Posted it as bug https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/2858 . As a temporary workaround,  I used gdal2tiles to create 0-12 zoom levels for the same. It is working fine. Created a custom python script to insert these tiles as blobs to GPKG database. It is taking extremely long time though.

Comment: I recommended to write to the mailing list first and ask if it is a bug. It also serves other GDAL users better because more people read the mailing list than GitHub issues and so they would be aware of the issue that indeed feels like a bug because 19376P x 11003L image does not give that error.